# Efficient hash function wrt. string concatenation?

Tags: c, string, performance, data-structures, hash

I'm experimenting with some data structures in a toy language, and since I do a lot of text processing I'd like string operations to be fast. I'm storing strings as immutable ropes with cached lengths and hashes. The goal is for the hash function to be performed only when a rope's leaf node is instantiated. Are there any existing hash functions out there that can do this?

My rope structure looks like this:

```
#define HASHLEN 128
#define HASHMUL 2
typedef unsigned long hashtype;
typedef struct rope rope;

// K&R2 hash function
hashtype hash(const char *s) {
    hashtype h = 0;
    while (*s != '\0') {
        h = h * HASHMUL + *s++;
    }
    return h; // won't be modded until the actual table access is performed
}

struct rope {
    unsigned weight;
    hashtype hash;
    rope *left;  // if NULL, indicates that r->right is a char *
    void *right; // if r->left is non-NULL, r->right is a rope *
};
```

and the concatenation function looks like this:

```
// integer exponentiation--by squaring
hashtype iexp(hashtype k, unsigned n);

rope *newrope(const char *s) {
    rope *r = (rope *) malloc(sizeof(rope));
    r->weight = strlen(s);
    r->hash = hash(s);
    r->left = NULL;
    r->right = (void *) s;

    return r;
}

rope *ropecat(rope *left, rope *right) {
    rope *r = (rope *) malloc(sizeof(rope));
    r->weight = left->weight + right->weight;
    r->hash = left->hash * iexp(HASHMUL, right->weight) + right->hash;
    r->left = left;
    r->right = (void *) right;

    return r;
}
```

A larger prime number would be better for `HASHMUL` (K&R2 uses 31, I've heard that 33 is "best"), but I'm concerned that with the rapid growth of the hash function for long strings, it might wrap around `ULONG_MAX` and break the hash mechanism, so I chose a number that might wrap more smoothly. Also setting `HASHMUL` to 2 lets `left->hash * iexp(HASHMUL->hash, right->weight)` be rewritten as `left->hash << right->weight`, and setting `HASHLEN` to 128 or another binary number lets me use `r->hash & (HASHLEN-1)` instead of `r->hash % HASHLEN`.

So that's the outline of what I'm trying to do. I'm looking for a hash function that's fast, sort-of distributive in constant time, and has a reasonable distribution. Does the naive K&R2 hash function work fine here, or should I use a different `HASHMUL`, or should I look for another hash function entirely?

Comment: Wrapping (by itself) isn't that bad, using an even number such as this is worse: it will actually discard a bit every time. So if the string is longer than how many bits there are in an `unsigned long`, the first character(s) won't affect the hash value at all. That's also why that `iexp` would usually return 0.

Comment: @harold wrap around inherently discards bits no matter what HASHMUL is. But you are right, setting HASHMUL to 2 means it will discard the bits in a very predictable manner, and will most likely lead to more collisions, which is going to worsen the time complexity of the data structure you are using. Those optimizations op mentioned won't make a difference then. That is why prime numbers are generally used.

Comment: @SeriousBusiness no it doesn't, multiplication by an odd number doesn't lose any information even if it wraps. Highly counter-intuitive I'll admit. But it's true, multiplication by an odd number can be undone perfectly, that is you can solve `for all x, x * odd * inv == x`, for example `x * 3 * 0xaaaaaaab == x` if you're working with 32bit numbers. Anyway long story short, if you multiply by an odd number arbitrarily many times, you'll still have all the information you started with. So only the addition will lose information now.

Comment: @harold If no information is lost then that means the hash function will never result in collisions. We all know that this is impossible.

Comment: @SeriousBusiness the addition loses information

Comment: @harold Ah I missed that part. Interesting. Is there a name for this property of multiplication by odd numbers?

Comment: @SeriousBusiness Math-jargon isn't really my thing, but you could call it invertible, in the sense of an invertible function. The thing to search for if you want to know more about it is modular multiplicative inverse.